# mysql innodb inner join with longtext very slow

Tags: mysql, performance, innodb, longtext

I migrated all MySQL tables of one project from MyISAM to InnoDB last week, in order to support transaction. I used the command of `alter table` for this.

Most works fine, however one particular query runs very very slow, and it always gives the error `Incorrect key file for table '/tmp/#sql_xxxx_x.MYI`

Later I narrowed down the problem into the inner join of 2 tables, the `user` table and `agreement` table. And the inner join took place between the foreign key field of `user` (i.e. `agreement_id`) and primary key field of `agreement` (i.e. `id`).

The `user` table has only 50,000 rows of data, and the `agreement` table has, well, one single row. And we have set up the index for the `agreement_id` of user.

In any case, this seems to be a very light-weighted query, but it turns out to be the whole bottle neck.

Here is the full schema of `agreement`:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `agreement` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `remark` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  `content` longtext NOT NULL,
  `is_active` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  `date_stamp` datetime NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=2 ;
```

One thing I doubt about is the longtext field of `remark` inside the `agreement` table, but we did NOT use the field for the inner join, in fact the query is slow even if we did NOT select `remark` in the query result.

finally, we converted the table of `agreement` from `innoDB` back to `MyISAM`, than everything becomes normal. And the query is finished in less than 1 second.

Now, my question is what actually is going on here? Does that mean once an innoDB table contains any text field, then the table could not be used for inner join?

I wish I could know the real reason so that I could avoid the same problems in the future.

thanks a lot.

Comment: Could you include query? Also `remark` is varchar(200) and `content` is longtext. So did you skip content or remark in `SELECT` statement?

Comment: yes, I skipped content and remove in the select statement. the final query is something like `select user.* from user inner join agreement on user.agreement_id = agreement.id`, but it's still very slow.

Comment: So try to skip remark as I've mentioned in my answer and check if it's faster.

Comment: ok, let me conclude what I got so far: 1. the query is one simple inner join, with primary key and index fully set. 2. if the `agreement` table is converted into innoDB, then problem disappears. 3. if the final sorting by `user.id` is removed, then the problem disappears. 4. if the longtext field of `content` is removed, then the problem disappears. 5. according to explain query of phpmyadmin, most of the time is spent on the sorting. But this expensive sorting seems only exist when it tries to join a InnoDB table with longtext field, even if this field is not used in the join/sort/select.

Answer (score 2):

This is a famous and tricky one. The most likely cause is that you're out of space in /tmp.

Here is a link I keep in my bookmarks that may help you: http://www.mysqlperformancetuning.com/a-fix-for-incorrect-key-file-for-table-mysql

> In my experience, limited though it is, the primary reason for seeing
>   this error message is because your tmpdir has run out of space. Like
>   me you'll check how much free space you have: 1Gb, 2Gb, 4Gb. It may
>   not be enough. And here's why: MySQL can create temporary tables
>   bigger than that in a matter of seconds, quickly filling up any free
>   space. Depending on the nature of the query and the size of the
>   database naturally.

You may also try a [REPAIR](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/fr/repair-table.html) on your table but to me it is as usefull as breakdancing :/

Comment: yes, indeed we saw that the tmp folder was quickly overwhelmed in seconds, but my question is, why a simple query like that would use so much memory? and why there is no such problem after I converted the table of 'agreement' from innodb back to myisam?

Comment: My guess is that innodb needs more memory as it is supporting transactions, foreign keys...

Comment: Have you checked the output of `EXPLAIN [your query]`? The query optimizer may have his funky ways sometimes (e.g. it could believe it's more efficient to create a temporary table containing the 50,000 users and for each of them, a copy of the one row of `agreement`)

Comment: I tried to use EXPLAIN SQL, and found that most of time is during the sorting. But if I converted into inno DB, then the problem disappears. And if I removed the longtext field from agreement, then the problem disappears too.

Answer (score 1):

InnoDB has it's own settings of buffer sizes etc. Check that out and if you can adjust it, go ahead. Just for test try to double them, if it helps, you may want to optimize it. It can make a big difference.

Some links that may help:

http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2007/11/03/choosing-innodb_buffer_pool_size/

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-buffer-pool.html

Comment: I tried to tune that but without luck, I have even tried to use /var/tmp for the tmp table partition, though it does not crash during query, but it becomes very very slow (took more than 10 min. to finish the query) ...

Answer (score 1):

Maybe problem here is `remark` field defined as `varchar(200)`? Remember that temporary and memory tables stores `varchar` with fixed length. So 50k rows with `varchar(200)` can consume a lot of memory even if they are all empty.

If this is the problem then you can try one of several things:

- If only few rows have value in column then create `varchar(200)` column with NULL allowed and always use NULL value instead of empty string
- Change `varchar(200)` to text (there is of course drawback - it will always use temporary table on disk)
- Maybe you don't need 200 characters? Try to use smaller `VARCHAR` size
- Try to adjust tmp_table_size and max_heap_table_size, so you could handle larger temporary tables in memory http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/internal-temporary-tables.html
- Use percona server as they support dynamic row format for memory tables http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2011/09/06/dynamic-row-format-for-memory-tables/

Comment: I tried to remove `content` field from the table, then it works fine, so I think it's not related with `remark`.

Answer (score 1):

What is the purpose of your query? I see from your comment that you only list the user information and nothing from agreement leading me to believe you are looking for users that has an agreement?
Since you are converting between engines it leads me to think you are doing cleanup before adding constraints. If so, consider a left join from the user table instead like:

```
select user.* from user left join agreement on user.agreement_id = agreement.id where user.agreement_id != 0;
```

If it's not cleanup, but simply looking for users with an agreement we make it simple

```
select user.* from user where user.agreement_id != 0;
```

If the purpose is something else, consider adding an index on user.agreement_id since an inner join may need it for speed. Let us know the real purpose and you may get better help.

Comment: acutally the query is automatically generated by django admin page, for some reason, when I need to show the user table, the django would crash and show above error. The reason I removed the agreement field selection is only to show that it's not related with the final query result.

Comment: Ok, then try run a 'repair table' on the two tables. mysql will probably then detect the missing/faulty key file and repair it for you. You may have to rename the original index file and restart mysql if you still have trouble.